# Can you have an adorner that extends outside of the bounds of the adorned control?

Tags: wpf, validation, adorner

We have a control that displays a small visual but we need to display a large error message.  We have the validation template showing up, but it seems to be clipped to the bounds of the adorned control.  Any easy way to let the adorned value render itself outside of that?

Comment: i have in mind that there is not easy solution. another approach is to use a popup but with that you have other restrictions/problems.

Comment: My work-around was just to add padding around it for now.  Not optimal by any means, but it worked enough to give us a usable hack.  Still, I'm gonna leave this open since I want a solution, not a work-around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered this issue before as well.  In my case, I had my control wrapped in a [AdornerDecorator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerdecorator.aspx), so the Adorner content was clipped to that control.  Once I removed the AdornerDecorator, the adorner was able to extend past that control.  My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13995967/718325) (and one of the links I provide there) explain/show this in more detail.

Comment: I think the key is specifying the AdornerDecorator which sets the scope of where the Adorner is.  If I specify that at a control higher up the hierarchy, that looks like it will solve the issue.  Thanks!